# Different object types

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

Quick shot,

in jQuery, `$("#doesNotExist")` returns "Object [ ]".

in JavaScript,

- `(function(){return new Object;}).call();` returns "Object{ }".
- `(function(){return Array;}).call();` returns "Array()" and
- `(function(){$n=[];return $n;}).call();` returns only "[ ]" and not "Object [ ]" either.

(Note `[]` vs `{}`, according to Firebug, latest version).

I'm not sure what to search for, but I'm wondering about the difference and how to get an equal result in JavaScript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This: `document.querySelectorAll("#doesNotExist")` also returns `[]`

Comment: @ Chris, updated my answer with some more in-depth data. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#doesNotExist")` returns an empty [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), the same way as `$()` would.

jQuery objects have an array-like structure, hence the Firebug representation: `Object[]` represents an array-like object.

---

I've looked up the Firebug source and found out how it classifies jQuery objects as array-like objects. The `isArrayLike` method returns `true` when a given object contains a `splice` method ([source](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/df2634e0f1cfe8e6539c0a88466ad5f97c4900ea/extension/content/firebug/lib/array.js#L35)).

So, for demo purposes, as of Firebug 12-13.0a, this is one way to force array-like display on Firebug:

```
console.log({
    0: 'hi',
    length: 1,
    splice: function(){} //makes Firebug display as array-like object
});
```

Results in:

[image: Object[ "hi" ]]

Answer (score 1):

`[]` implies an array, whereas `{}` is a single object.

Comment: But `(function(){return Array;}).call();` returns "Array()" and not "Object [ ]"?

Comment: While `(function(){$n=[];return $n;}).call();` is only "[ ]" and not "Object [ ]"

Comment: So in order to generate a jQuery compatible, empty array of DOM objects, I am required to select `$("doesntexist")` and can't repoduce it otherwise? This seems kind of QND to me...

Comment: You could always look at jQuery's implementation and imitate that.